# Display a list of products that belong to a specific term

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to generate a list of products that belong to the attribute `pa_maat` and term `L`.
The snippet below creates a list of products and all it's variations.
How do I alter the code to only show products for the term `L`?

Updated:

Attribute: `pa_maat`
Terms: `S`,`M`,`L`,`XL`,`2XL`,`3XL`

Attribute: `pa_kleur`
Terms: `wit`,`sportgrijs`,`zwart`

Basicly the script should display 3 variations per product as each of the 3 colors in `pa_kleur` come in size `L`.

**Shortcode**

```
[single_variations]
```

**Code snippet**

```
add_shortcode( 'single_variations', 'bs_single_variations_shortcode' );
 
function bs_single_variations_shortcode() {  
   $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'product_variation',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 50,
      'paged' => absint( empty( $_GET['product-page'] ) ? 1 : $_GET['product-page'] ),
   ));
   if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      ob_start();
      wc_setup_loop(
         array(
            'name' => 'single_variations',
            'is_shortcode' => true,
            'is_search' => false,
            'is_paginated' => true,
            'total' => $query->found_posts,
            'total_pages' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'per_page' => $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ),
            'current_page' => max( 1, $query->get( 'paged', 1 ) ),
         )
      );
      woocommerce_pagination();
      woocommerce_product_loop_start();
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
         $query->the_post();
         wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
      }
      woocommerce_product_loop_end();
      woocommerce_pagination();
      wp_reset_postdata();
      wc_reset_loop();
      return ob_get_clean();
   }
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The args are wrong.

```
add_shortcode( 'single_variations', 'bs_single_variations_shortcode' );

function bs_single_variations_shortcode() {  
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product', // WooCommerce product post type
        'posts_per_page' => -1,   // Retrieve all products
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Only published products
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type', // WooCommerce product type taxonomy
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'variable', // Filter by variable products
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_maat', // The taxonomy for the attribute
                'field'    => 'slug',    // We're searching by term slug
                'terms'    => 'l',       // The term slug we're looking for
             ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        ob_start();
        wc_setup_loop(
           array(
              'name' => 'single_variations',
              'is_shortcode' => true,
              'is_search' => false,
              'is_paginated' => true,
              'total' => $query->found_posts,
              'total_pages' => $query->max_num_pages,
              'per_page' => $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ),
              'current_page' => max( 1, $query->get( 'paged', 1 ) ),
           )
        );
        woocommerce_pagination();
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
           $query->the_post();
           wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        woocommerce_pagination();
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wc_reset_loop();
        return ob_get_clean();
     }
     return;
 }
```

Answer update. Keep in mind pagination is complicated in this situation because some parent products may have 3 variations other 1 and breaking to pages will require custom pagination (atleast this is my opinion).

```
add_shortcode( 'single_variations', 'bs_single_variations_shortcode' );

function bs_single_variations_shortcode() {  
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product', // WooCommerce product post type
        'posts_per_page' => -1,   // Retrieve all products
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Only published products
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type', // WooCommerce product type taxonomy
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'variable', // Filter by variable products
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_maat', // The taxonomy for the attribute
                'field'    => 'slug',    // We're searching by term slug
                'terms'    => 'l',       // The term slug we're looking for
             ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            global $product;
            // Get all variations for the product.
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

            foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                $attributes = $variation['attributes'];

                // Check if the variation has the 'pa_maat' attribute and 'l' as its term.
                if (isset($attributes['attribute_pa_maat']) && $attributes['attribute_pa_maat'] === 'l') {
                    // Display the variation as a separate product.
                    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                }
            }
        endwhile;
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    endif;
 }
```

Final version. After some research this is how should be done.

```
add_shortcode( 'single_variations', 'bs_single_variations_shortcode' );

function bs_single_variations_shortcode() {  
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product_variation',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'attribute_pa_maat', // The meta key for the 'pa_maat' attribute
                'value' => 'l', // The desired term 'l'
                'compare' => '=', // Compare for exact match
            ),
        ),    
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        endwhile;
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
        ));    
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
 }
```

Comment: Your code generates only 1 variation with the term `L`. I have updated my question to clarify

Comment: Returns one because its returning the parent product. What you want is different from the OP.

Comment: Yes I noticed the question was not clear enough. I have added the correct information.

Comment: My final code should work for you. Let me know.

Comment: Your final code works as intended. Thank you for your time and research. Answer accepted.

Comment: Glad to hear. Also if you insist on using woo pagination you can use the wc_setup_loop but from my test returns paged url as ?product-page=2 instead of /page/2 so maybe with some additional modifications could work with woo pagination if you want to go there.